# Data Binding problem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to do something like this diagram [Data Binding Diagram](http://www.procesta.com/Images/diagram.png). 
If i update TextBox text Then update TextBlock text and Property and if i change Property Value then also update Textbox and textBlock text. Please tell me how can i do it using WPF ????

Thank`s For Help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand right your question. Are the two Textboxes in the same view or in different?
Here a solution with 2 textboxes in the same view:

View (xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Name="mainWindow">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="UpperTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=LowerTextBox, Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Name="LowerTextBox" Text="{Binding MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

View-Codebehind (xaml.cs):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }        
    } 

    private string _myValue;
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return _myValue; }
        set
        {
            _myValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
        }
    }
}
```